# Linear or Intrinsically Linear Regression Model?

Tags: linear-regression

I have the following model and I'm not sure whether its linear or if it can be made linear. I don't know if it can be considered linear already with the log and X^2 or if I have to rewrite it.

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mXK0.png)

Comment: This is a linear model. The 'linear' in linear model refers to linearity in the betas, not the x's. No rewriting necessary.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wow, you made this immediately a lot more clearer for me. I was looking at the x's and I was ignoring the betas since they were constants.